# Conflicted edit rejection reason not translated

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

When your edit gets rejected because it conflicted, you get this message:

[image: Conflicted edit rejection reason: not translated]

The rejection reason is still in English.

Can it please be translated?

Comment: Your edit conflicted with the mine. I only saw that after I had saved it, sorry.

Comment: @Victor That's no problem :)